# Is the d in "lived in" flapped in American English?

Tags: pronunciation, american-accent

I am trying to say the sentence :

> how long have you lived in the US

[My pronunciation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9u2y8g194gr428p/SER_Unit2_how-long-have2.m4a?dl=0) of "*lived in*" feels so heavy handed compared to this [audio recording](https://rachelsenglish.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/08LivingintheUS-01.mp3).

I wonder, is the **d** flapped? It should be flapped because it is between two vowels. In the above recording, are there other sounds that are being dropped?

Comment: The 'd' in "lived" is generally pronounced with the [t] sound. I don't hear a flap at all.

Comment: @user178049: with a [t]?!

Comment: @Void Actually I wanted to write /t/, but it felt weird to say "a /t/ sound" because /t/ is not a sound. But are you implying that it is not a /t/.

Comment: @user178049: Well, I've never heard 'lived' pronounced with a [t].

Comment: @Void I just confirmed.. Yes it is /d/. I was mistaken. However, when pronounced in isolation and when it is followed by a silence, it could be /t/ due to a final-obstruent devoicing.

Comment: @user178049: When the /d/ is next to a voiceless sound, it is usually realised as [t] (not /t/). same goes for pre-silence position

Comment: @Void I did mean to write [t]! :) I must have been tripping.

Comment: @user178049 I have added my recording in the original post, it's difficult for me to pinpoint what I am doing wrong with the "d"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flapping occurs when the 't' or 'd' is in an unstressed syllable and flanked by vowels ('better' [b**ɛɾɚ**]). The 'd' in *lived in* isn't flapped because it's preceded by a 'v' which blocks flapping: /ˈlɪ**vd**.ɪn/

Comment: Thanks, is any other sound dropped? Is very difficult for me to pronounce "lived in the", this is my version: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4buxa8x8hiz8hsh/SER_Unit2_how-long-have.m4a?dl=0

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the realization may vary. For example the "d" in "loved you" may be pronounced as [dʒ].

Comment: @Emy: You're dropping the 'd' in 'lived'. You need to practise pronouncing the /-vd/ cluster. :)

Comment: @Void, thanks, you see, if I put the "d" in, it does not sound as in the original recording: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9u2y8g194gr428p/SER_Unit2_how-long-have2.m4a?dl=0

Comment: @Emy: Because the original speaker seems to be a native speaker of American English. You need practice to achieve that pronunciation. :P English consonant clusters are harder to pronounce than those of many other languages